# How Can I Filter an Array from Another Array in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Goal:**
I have two arrays: One of vehicles scheduled for a day, and one of all vehicles. If a driver wants to use a vehicle on Monday, my program should check all driver's schedules for Monday and see what vehicles are being used and display a list of available vehicles BEFORE the user can select one (the select dropdown should never show anything that isn't available)

I can't seem to get Ember to filter the data. It's all or nothing. I can't get the filtered data. Are you willing to take a look?

Github Repository: [https://github.com/djbreen7/ejs-taxi-app/blob/master/app/routes/schedules/view.js][1]

**routes/schedules/view.js**

```
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('schedule', params.schedule_id);
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('schedule', model);

    var self = this;
    this.store.findAll('schedule').then(function(schedules) {
      controller.set('schedules', schedules);
      var scheduledVehicles = schedules.filter(function(day) {
        if (day.get('day_of_week') === model.get('day_of_week') && day.get('vehicle.id')) {
          return self.store.findRecord('vehicle', day.get('vehicle.id'));
        }
      });
      var vehicles = self.store.findAll('vehicle');
      controller.set('vehicles', vehicles.filter(function(vehicle) {
        return scheduledVehicles.indexOf(vehicle) === -1;
      }));
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all these filtering should be done in backend server.

Anyway for doing that in client side, you shouldn't use async in `setupController`. I mean don't use ember data finding in `setupController`.

```
model(params){
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    schedule: this.store.findRecord('schedule', params.schedule_id),
    allSchedules: this.store.findAll('schedule'),
    allVehicles: this.store.findAll('vehicle')
  });
}

setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('schedule', model.schedule); 
    controller.set('schedules', model.allSchedules); 

    var self = this;
    var scheduledVehicles = schedules.filter(function(day) {
        if (day.get('day_of_week') === model.get('day_of_week') && day.get('vehicle.id')) {
          return self.store.peekRecord('vehicle', day.get('vehicle.id'));
        }
      });
    var destVehicles = model.allVehicles.filter(function(vehicle) {
        return scheduledVehicles.indexOf(vehicle) === -1;
      }));
    controller.set('vehicles', destVehicles);
}
```

Also for this usage I recommend using `computed` properties placed in controllers even.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I had tried `Ember.RSVP.hash` before but I run into issues with the model disappearing if I refresh the browser.